# ASP.NET MVC - Using RadioButtonFor in MVC4 Razor View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have three Partial Views to Render from Controller. The Radio Buttons are not connected Model.

1. RadioButton1 - when clicked, it renders GetView1
2. RadioButton2 - when clicked, it renders GetView2
3. RadioButton3 - when clicked, it renders GetView3

**Controller**

```
    public class RadioRenderController : Controller
{
    // GET: RadioRender
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult GetView1()
    {
        return PartialView("_DemoView1");
    }

    public ActionResult GetView2()
    {
        return PartialView("_DemoView2");
    }

    public ActionResult GetView3()
    {
        return PartialView("_DemoView3");
    }
}
```

I have this View below. How do I re-write it by not being connected to Model.

```
    <div>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.RadioButton1, "1", new { @onclick = "GetView1();" }) RadioButton1
</div>
<div>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.RadioButton1, "2", new { @onclick = "GetView2();" }) RadioButton2
</div>
<div>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.RadioButton1, "3", new { @onclick = "GetView3();" }) RadioButton3
</div>
```

The issue is, how do I create a normal Grouped Radio Button that is not tied to Model, but each will render a Partial View. Is it not possible to remove

> m => m

from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately all the html helper methods renders pure HTML which the browsers can understand and parse. So you may simply write the HTML makrup for the radio buttons. Give the same `name` attribute value for all four radio buttons so that they are grouped together.

Also, you do not need 4 different methods on these if you are going to do the same thing , which is loading an associated action method result via ajax. You can use same code for all 4 radio button click events, but just use different urls (to the action method which returns the partial view result).

We can keep these urls in html5 `data` attributes.

```
<div>
    <label>Grid 1</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-views"  
                        data-url="@Url.Action("GetView1","Home")" value="1" />

    <label>Grid 2</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-views"  
                        data-url="@Url.Action("GetView2","Home")" value="2" />

    <label>Grid 3</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-views"  
                        data-url="@Url.Action("GetView3","Home")" value="3" />

    <label>Grid 4</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-views"  
                        data-url="@Url.Action("GetView4","Home")"" value="4" />
</div>
<div id="grid-view">Result from the ajax call will replace this content</div>
```

Now you can use unobutrusive javascript to wire up the `click` event on these radio buttons and read the clicked items value/data attribute values. You can read the `data-url` attribute value of the clicked radio button and make an ajax call to that to get the partial view result and upate the DOM element's inner html with the response. You can use the jQuery [`ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) method to make the call to the action method and when the result arrives (the `done` handler of the `$.ajax` method), udpate the content of the div with id `grid-view`, using the `html` method.

```
$(function(){

      $("input[name='radio-views']").click(function() {
        var $clicked = $(this);
        alert("value : " + $clicked.val());

        var url = $clicked.data("url");
        alert("Going to make an ajax call to url : "+url);

        $.ajax({url: url}).done(function(res) {
            $("#grid-view").html(res);
        }).fail(function(x, a, e) {
            alert(e);
        });
    });

});
```